# Building POCO (C++ lib) fails due to wrong Visual Studio Version

Tags: windows, visual-c++, poco

I am trying to build the POCO C++ with Visual Studio 2010. As the developers don't offer a suitable solution for VS 10 yet, I used the conversion manager to convert a VS 9 solution. Unfortunately, building fails with the following error message:

Error   2   error : 0x2 trying to open file .  C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\evnu\Desktop\src\poco\Foundation\mc

I am not acustomed to work with Visual Studio and therefore unable to figure where to fix this problem. Do you guys have any hint where to search for this bug? I think it's hidden in some build-file.

Regards, evnu

[edit]
I forgot to add the URL pointing to the POCO Project:
http://pocoproject.org/
[/edit]

Comment: The Poco developers are working to enable compiling it on Visual Studio 2010. See http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=725709&aid=3122217&group_id=132964 for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the the README file in the poco root folder documents that mc.exe has some issues when the path contains spaces. Try to place your src folder in your root or somewhere else that does not contain spaces.
HTH.

Comment: That sounds about right. I think I had some issues with space in paths before. I'll try that ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your using the express edition of visual studio 10.  Download the Windows SDK in addition to the express edition as the problem you are seeing is the message compiler is being called but missing which is needed to build the windows port of POCO C++.

If this is not the case then you need to examine your path because the mc.exe is not being found.